# How to return different view, but presererve ViewModel in OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to return a different view if a condition is met. I want to preserve the Model passed into the view from the action.

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var subAction = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["subaction"].ToString();
        var action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subAction))
        {
            var view = (ViewResultBase) (filterContext.Result);
            filterContext.Result = View(action + subAction, view.ViewData.Model);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

When doing it this way I get an "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`". Obviously, the Model haven't been set?

The reason I'm doing it this way, is that I want to keep the naming of the view as simple as possible. And my URL looks like this: `/Global/Modules/Admin/Users/Create`. That would return the view "UsersCreate". Which works. But the Model is either empty or null!

**UPDATE**

Actually. It just hit me. The behaviour is correct. Because I'm only returning a View. The action is never executed. The Users-action gets executed, but returns the view UsersCreate. How can I do a RedirectToAction kinda thing, without actually redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) is run before the action so no model exists yet. You may try with [`OnActionExecuted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted.aspx) which is called once the action returns an `ActionResult`.

Comment: But then it's too late to change the View. I get an `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type[..]`. The data passed is a list of users. I'm passing a viewmodel class `UsersCreate`. The list of users is the Model of the `Users` view.

Comment: Actually. It just hit me. The behaviour is correct. Because I'm only returning a View. The Action is never executed. The `Users` action gets executed, but returns the view `UsersCreate`. How can I do a `RedirectToAction` kinda thing, without actually redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    ...
    if (needToRedirect)
    {
       ...
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
       return;
    }
    ...
 }
```